issue with a for loop and a function
I'm making a beginner level problem and i cant get my code to count how many times i got to the last if, with the code i have now it says that c is referenced before being assigned.
i was hoping to get certain numbers in a list from a to b and to also get the count on how many times i got those type of numbers so i did a silly function that repeats itself until the ranged is finished.
c = 0
def primito(num1):
  for i in range(1,num1):
    if i % 2 !=0:
      if i % 3!=0:
        if i % 5!=0:
          print(i, "es un numero primo ")
          c+=1
          return c
numero = int(input("escriba un numero: "))

primito(numero)

print("los primos son", c)


What do you expect return c inside your loops to do?

The final if block has a return statement in it, which means it will only execute once, because return makes the function terminate immediately.

@PM77-1 i wrote that just to get back the value of c after each loop because i thought that maybe not having a return was why i didn't get the c value updated, which is my main issue i cant get the count of how many times the loop got there.

This question is similar to: How can I use `return` to get back multiple values from a loop? Can I put them in a list?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to return after the loop. However, your logic is wrong, because it ignores the fact that 2, 3 and 5 are prime, and your conditions will allow 1 to be counted as a prime. There is a better way to do this, anyway, using sum, map, and all.
# count all primes within a range 2 to num (inclusive)
def enumerar_primo(num:int) -> int:
    # base primes
    base = 2,3,5
    
    # returns True/False is prime
    def primito(i:int) -> bool: 
        return i in base or all(i%x for x in base)
        
    # map the range to True/False values and sum  
    return sum(map(primito, range(2,num+1)))

numero = int(input("escriba un numero: "))

c = enumerar_primo(numero)

print("los primos son", c)

For clarity: map will pass every iteration of the range to primito, and store all of the returns as True or False. Then sum will sum all of the values in map, essentially telling you how many True values were present. A True value means a number was prime, so the sum is also telling you how many primes you have.

Are you sure this is right? If the input number is 11, the output is 6 but there are 5 prime numbers in the [inclusive] range 2-11

@sighup- I didn't consider that the modulo part is actually counting the "1". Probably the easiest way for me to solve this is to simply start the range at 2. It should be fixed now.
